# Keyboard layout Croatian Apple Wireless keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, apple

Is there a hr_HR keyboard layout for ubuntu and how can I install it?

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my old iMac, but I can't set up the keyboard properly. I have the Apple wireless keyboard with Croatian layout.

I have tried all the offered Croatian layouts, and they all offer hr_US - so my `- _ ? /` keys are reversed for example. How could I find a proper keyboard layout - or can I maybe customize the existing one?

Comment: You may want to try some Serbian layouts too, e.g. Serbian (Latin). But it sounds to me as if there is a need to customize it a bit.

Comment: Thanks, haven't thaught of that.